# I implemented caching in my WebPages site, but I don't think it's working

Tags: c#, .net, caching, razor, webmatrix

## Edit:


Is there a way to monitor the cache?

---

I decided to implement caching to improve the performance of the product pages. Currently, each product page contains minimum 3000 entries.

With caching, this should substantially improve the loading time of these pages. But I am not sure if my implementation even works, because I have since added new records to the Database, and those changes are reflecting in the browser.

Any ideas why the caching isn't working?

```
public class Acquire
{
    public class All
    {
        public WebGrid Products(String Range, String Category)
        {
            String cacheItemKey = Range + Category;
            bool cacheHit = true;
            Grid = WebCache.Get(cacheItemKey);

            if (Grid == null)
                cacheHit = false;

            if (cacheHit == false)
            {
                results = database.Products.Where(
                                   x => x.Range == Range && x.Category == Category);

                Grid = new WebGrid(results, canPage: false);

                // Add it to the Cache.
                WebCache.Set(cacheItemKey, Grid, 1, false);
            }

            return Grid;
        }
    }
}
```

In-case you're wondering why it's wrapped up in Classes and Methods; it's mainly to keep the pages nice and clean, and to reduce code repetition and help prevent error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you're caching the results of your query, not the query itself. I.e make sure you enumerate the query. The easiest way would be to create your webgrid with
    results.ToList()

Edit:
This is what I meant.

```
results = database.Products.Where(
    x => x.Range == Range 
    && x.Category == Category).ToList();
```

You can monitor the cache by setting a break point in your code and check to see if you ever get a non-null value from `WebCache.Get(cacheItemKey)`.

Comment: Ah, compiler don't like that. Says `MyModel.Product` does not contain a definition for `ToList()`.

Comment: Um, the code is in my question. The rest of the code is just `grid.getHtml(...)` and there's nothing wrong with that code since it's been working for months and hasn't been changed.

Comment: @JamesKent is `database.Products.Where(...)` not LINQ? Is it a custom method? I assumed that `database.Products` was some `IEnumerable<Product>` and that your results were also some `IEnumerable<Product>` which definitely has a ToList() method (in the System.Linq namespace).

Comment: Erm, the `database.Products.Where` part is part of Entity Framework.

Comment: @JamesKent so what type does your `database.Products.Where` return?

Comment: It returns a bunch of stuff from specified columns. Presumably IEnumerable.